# Extracting terminal nodes from cforest in R

Tags: r, random-forest, treenode

I would like to add to each row the relevant terminal node.
Here is my code:

```
library(party)
dat1 <- fread('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/abalone.data',stringsAsFactors=T)

## split data to train and test
set.seed(123)
dat1 <- subset(dat1, !is.na(V1))
smp_size<-100
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(dat1)), size = smp_size)
train <- dat1[train_ind, ]
test <- dat1[-train_ind, ]

ct <- ctree(V1 ~ ., data = train)
```

I would like to add both to train and test column (`train$TN` and `test$TN`) respectively that will contain the relevant terminal in which each row resides.
for the train, I tried:

```
train$TN<-factor (ct@where)
```

and got:

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

For the test I tried:

```
test$TN<-predict(ct, test[,V2:V9],type = "node")
```

and got:

```
Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' should be one of “response”, “prob”
```

Comment: I get no error for `train$TN <- factor(ct@where)` or the test predictor, and that does seem to be what you are looking for. Can you try this in a fresh R session? Also, you should likely either `library(data.table)` or fully qualify the reference to `fread` via `data.table::fread`.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Please explain what you mean. I only want to get the terminal nodes for the training data of randomforest....

Comment: You said the two bits of R code to do that generated errors. When I ran them they did not. And you use `fread` without a `library()` call for `data.table` making your code not reproducible.

Comment: did you try `install.packages('partykit')` and then `test$TN<-predict(ct, test[,V2:V9],type = "node")`? I couldn't get the node either and then stumbled upon your question and tried with `type=node` and it worked! but i had partykit loaded already.